# Google Apps email forwarding from non-existing email addresses

Tags: email, g-suite, forwarding

We're planning to move all our corporate emails to Google Apps, but I couldn't find an answer to the following question anywhere. Hope anybody will help.

Currently, we have 10 real email addresses (that is, for everyone in our organization) plus a handful of administrative ones (like `support@`, `registrationrequest@`, etc.). After moving to Google Apps I'm only planning to keep these 10 "real" addresses and leave `support@` as the only "administrative" address: there's no benefit in paying 50$ a year for an address which will receive a dozen emails a year.

So here's my problem: is it possible to tell Google Apps to forward all emails sent to an unknown (unregistered) address to a particular email box so that all emails sent to, say, `registrationrequest@` will eventually end up in `support@`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called a "catch-all" address: there is information on setting this up at http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33962

Note that this is a good way to get a lot of spam, but hopefully that will all get filtered.

Answer (score 2):

Those administrative accounts could be handled by creating groups within Google Apps that then redirect mail to one or more individual e-mail accounts. Google doesn't charge for the group addresses. Also, Google just added support for Google Groups like functionality within Google Apps, so the groups can be more like discussion forums.

You can also create aliases for each e-mail account so that antong@ would receive e-mail for support@ and sales@. Since Google only charges you for the primary account and mailbox you get the aliases for free. However, groups are the more flexible way of handling this.